# Excel VBA selection.replace and if replaced put text in column a of the replaced row

Tags: excel, vba

I have some macro like:

```
Columns("F:M").Select
Selection.Replace What:=",", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

But i want to put the current date (or even just a string of text) to be put in cell A of the row where a replace occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine you will need to change your replace to a find and replace. Something like:

```
Dim c As Range
Columns("F:M").Select
Set c = Selection.Find(What:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not c Is Nothing Then
    Do
        c.Replace What:=",", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Cells(c.Row, 1).Value = Date
        Set c = Selection.FindNext(c)
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing
End If
```

Comment: +1 `SearchFormat` and `ReplaceFormat` were added in the 2003 version, I think, but I reckon the two arguments can safely be deleted for earlier versions of Excel.

Comment: @Remou, I actually tested without them on Excel2000, and only added them in because they exist in the question. So yeah, it works ^_^