# Repair incorrectly formatted time 'hh:nn:ss' when h=0

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm doing a report which calculates people's time to determine their pay. We pull reports from our servers and paste them into Excel to do the calculations. I have run into an issue when pulling the data: if the time they logged in for was less than an hour our formula is not working:

`=IF(E159="","",((HOUR(E159)+(MINUTE(E159)+(SECOND(E159)/60))/60)))`

This gives an error (`#value`) if the time is `:34:15`, but if it's `00:34:15` then it's fine.

Formatting the cell does not appear to work.

I'd like to  go through this column and add the `00` to all values missing it, and I need some help or guidance from there.

[Another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026423/excel-vba-selection-replace-and-if-replaced-put-text-in-column-a-of-the-replaced) looks like it may help, but I'm unsure on how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that The tiem is in cell E159 from your above formula, you can append a 0 to the start of the time. This will fix all the times that have the hour missing and won't affect the other lines.

```
="0"&E159
```

You can then replace all of the `E159` references in your original formula with this edit so that it looks like this:

```
=IF(E159="","",((HOUR("0"&E159)+(MINUTE("0"&E159)+(SECOND("0"&E159)/60))/60)))
```

While it's hard to read, it does the trick.

While that answers you question.. I think that there is a better way to achieve this formula.

It looks like the end result you're looking for is the time converted to hours, with mulutes and seconds as a decimel to the next hour. You can achieve this by doing:

```
=E159*24
```

Which will give you the same result as your original formula.
And then to combine that with my first answer to get a formula that looks like:

```
=("0" & E159)*24
```

This approach is much easier to read / edit and provides the same output.

**Why This Works**

Excel stores all dates as whole numbers, and all times as a decimel % to a day.
So when Excel is stores 12 hours it saves it as .5 because it is half of a day.
By dividing the time output by 24 we are converting the entire time value down from a % of day to a % of hours.

Comment: does the trick is an understatement hard to read or not its solved without using a macro. and a wonderful way at that. pure genious sir

Comment: Try the last formula I posted too! It does the same thing but is a lot easier to read. Glad to help.

Comment: The original formula will convert 8:30 to 8.5 - that requires multiplication by 24 not division. Also you can concatenate zero to the start of a time value with no effect so you don't really need an IF, you can just concatenate zero in all cases, i.e. `=(0&E159)*24`

Comment: @barryhoudini Thanks for the catch and insight. I updated my later answers accordingly.

Comment: No problem, I edited the last formula too because you still had that as /24